# SQLSTATE[28000] error for Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've already solved this silly issue, but I'm posting this in case I run into it again.

I tried updating my database this morning, but this happened:

```
$ php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force

In PDOConnection.php line 47:

  SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'QR_Lunch'.


In PDOConnection.php line 43:

  SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'QR_Lunch'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

I deleted it yesterday, because I needed to update the schema with new columns that couldn't be updated unless I deleted all data, so I just dropped the whole database and then forgot about it the next day.